# Ubuntu 12.04.4 boot problem with Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 on a separate partition with Windows 7 as my Primary OS (installed first)
I let Ubuntu do the distribution of the partition under the "Install Side-by-side" option
When booting up, there is no prompt asking for ubuntu so I googled it and some forums said to install EasyBCD and add an entry

I did that and I got a new boot option, but when I boot into it I get a Grub4Dos command prompt asking for grub> commands

I tried the following:

- `startx` - command not found
- `boot` - error 8 kernel must be loaded before booting
- `sudo apt-get install...` - sudo not found

I've been breaking my head over this for the past 4 hours, but I can't figure it out.
I've tried reinstalling 5 times, I've looked at all the possible forums I could think of and none of the solutions people had before helped.

Computer specs:

- Inter i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz
- 32GB RAM
- Z87-G45 MSI MoBo
- ASUS NVidia GeForce GTX770

OSs installed:

- Primary: Windows 7 Professional
- Secondary: Ubuntu 12.04.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: As I stated above sudo commands don't work

Comment: Please read carefully. You can use Ubuntu Installation media which _has_ `sudo`.

Comment: I found out what happened.. when Ubuntu automatically created the partitions, it just kept them as ntfs partitions split down the middle into /media and /home

I just managed to fix it by actually going in and manually partitioning off the hard drive

Comment: Did you figured out how to fix the bootloader?

Comment: I didn't need to after I manually remade the partitions, just booted into the bootloader normally and I just selected the OS I wanted